# Trouble when trying to define a write_all() socket function in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

I am currently using this function in a C client program. Everything seems to work fine but when the server to which this client is connected is shut down, `write_all()` returns 4 (that's `len`) instead of the expected -1.

```
int write_all(int sock, const void *buf, size_t len)
{
    int buf_size = len;
    while(len > 0)
    {
        int result = write(sock, buf, len);
        if(result < 0)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return result;
        }
        buf += result;
        len -= result;
    }
    return buf_size;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing in this function? Is there any other function I can call beforehand to make sure the server is still up?

Thanks

Comment: `write` may return `0` depending on the kind of the socket. Have you thought about that?

Comment: I have. But for the problem at hand, it doesn't make a difference. Does it?

Comment: Is buf your receive or send buffer? What actions do you take on your client prior to shutting down the server? Is the server on the the same computer?

Comment: The tests were made with the server on the same computer. I'm not doing anything prior to connecting + shutting down the server + sending this write message. The buf is the send buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You say "shut down", do you mean that you switch the power off, without gracefull TCP closing?

In that case write call returns with success. Data is in TCP sending buffer, and TCP stack does not yet know that peer is down. Program will get EPIPE or other error during later calls.

TCP stack will try retransmission a while, before making decision of connection failure.

Comment: Yes, the server is being crashed on purpose. How should I proceed, then, to check if the server is still up or down?

Comment: I that case, the client can not know is the server down, or is there temporary problem in network (too much traffic etc). So it is better to keep going. The client will probably calls recv()/read() after sending. If server is down, the receiving calls will fail after a while. At this point you can do necessary actions.

Comment: I have colleagues with similar code that when trying to write to the shut down socket will yell out a "Broken pipe" error. So there must be a way for the client to know when the server is down. I've looked superficially at their code and I'd say its 99% the same. There must be some flag or something that makes a difference.

Comment: Doesn't `write()` **only** return the full number of bytes it should have written, in case the delivery of **all** data had been acknowledged by the receiver (as this is TCP)? What in this case would mean the data had been at least fully received on the server side **before** the server went down.

Comment: Maybe. Yet I need a solution for this :( Isn't there a way to force a broken pipe message when trying to send data to a shut down server?

Comment: "shut down socket" and "switching power off" are two different scenarios. When a server closes the socket (gracefully or not), then TCP stack of server will send FIN or RST packet to the client. In that case clients write will fail immediately, because TCP stack of client knows that peer is down. 

But if you switch power off or OS of server crash, then the server won't send FIN or RST packet. And client won't know immediately that server is down. 

There is an exception for this: If client and server are directly connected with cross cable, then client see that interface is not up any more.

Comment: If server program crash, then OS of server will close TCP connections. And again, the client knows that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you won't get around implementing some sort of hand shake.

As if it's not enough for your sender to know the data it send had been fully received (what I assume is the case), but it also needs to know if any kind on processing had been done on it by the receiver, you expect more from the socket's mechanics than they can provide ...

The sockets are just the transmitter.

Comment: As stated in the other post, i've seen other similar projects where in someway the are sockets "throwing" a broken pipe error when trying to make a write() to a shut down server. so there must be a way.

Comment: @devoured elysium: They do this indeed in case they were not able to deliver (all of) their data.  Anyhow in your situation it seems to me that the server *did* receive the sent data properly *before* it went done. If the server would have not read it (all), `write()` would not have returned the number of bytes it should have had written (as already mentioned ... ;-) but -1 and set errno most propably to `EPIPE`.

Comment: What so ever: If it's really important for your client to know if any data it sent had perhaps been lost, you might start thinking about using an app/ level hand shake protocol.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm assuming TCP here.

From the return value, I gather that the client managed to write 4 bytes to the send buffer before learning that the server closed its end or otherwise disappeared. If it disappeared without proper closing, the only way to know would be a timed-out send. The next `write`, `shutdown` or `close` after that will get the error.

If you want to get prompt notification of disappearing endpoints without having to constantly send data, you can activate the socket keepalive option. In Linux, that would be a `setsockopt(..., SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, ...)`, and `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, `TCP_KEEPCNT` at the `SOL_TCP` level.